# jQuery insertAfter last item

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<div class="main">
    <a class="blah">blah1</a>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <a class="blah">blah2</a>
</div>
<div class="main reply">
    <a class="blah">blah3</a>
</div>
<div class="main reply">
    <a class="blah">blah4</a>
</div>
<div class="main reply">
    <a class="blah">blah5</a>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <a class="blah">blah6</a>
</div>
<div class="main reply">
    <a class="blah">blah7</a>
</div>
```

on click of `a.blah`, I need to append something like `<div class="new">xxx</div>` to the latest `.reply` after the **parent** `.main`, it means it should find the latest `.reply` agter the parent of the `a.blah`, and it should not cross to another `.main`, here is what I coded (but not working):

```
$('.blah').on('click', function(){
    var new_add = '<div class="new">xxx</div>';
    $(this).parents('div.main').next('.main:last').append(new_add);
});
```

How should I fix this?
Thanks

Comment: IDs must be unique. Use classes for repeated things.

Comment: There's no `class="reply_comment"` in your HTML.

Comment: @Barmar it is class in my real code, here I made it simple and forgot about it, and I fixed the `.reply_comment`, it's `.main`

Comment: @behz4d checkout http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/msp75/3/

Comment: I edited your HTML to number the blahs. Can you explain what you want to happen when you click on each of them? Where should xxx go in each case?

Comment: OK, on click of `.blah`(2), the `new_add` should be inserted after `blah 5`

Comment: I think http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/msp75/4/ will do

Comment: @behz4d on click of which `blah`? 1 or 2

Comment: @ArunPJohny your code inserts `new_add` into the last `.reply`, this should be inserted AFTER it. thanks

Comment: @behz4d in that case http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/msp75/5/ use `.after()` instead of `.append()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny it worked perfectly, please add an answer so I could mark it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments

```
$('.blah').on('click', function(){
    var new_add = '<div class="new">xxx</div>';
    $(this).closest('.main').nextUntil('.main:not(.reply)').addBack().last().after(new_add);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/msp75/)

1. [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) find the immediate ancestor matching the selector
2. [.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) finds all the `.reply` elements coming after the current `.main` without crossing over a `.main` without `.reply`
3. [.addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) adds back the current parent, incase the next `.main` is not `.reply`
4. [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/) finds the last element from the matched set
5. [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) inserts the passed element after the matched set of element

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.blah').on('click', function(){
    var new_add = '<div class="new">xxx</div>';
    $(this).parents('div.main').siblings('.main:last').append(new_add);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h3D25/1/)

Comment: Wouldn't this also add to a previous comment?

Comment: Yes, it would. Your question didn't mention anything about that.

Comment: this goes to the last .main and add it there, this should be before the another main and after `$(this).parent('.main').last(.reply)`

Comment: Sorry, I based it on your code, not your words. I don't know how to get to the latest reply without crossing over into another main.